# PHP exec() not working with ffmpeg but works in cmd

Tags: php, ffmpeg

it works in command line

```
 ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i demo.mp4 -f image2 -y test2.jpg
```

but it doesn't work in PHP using exec();
    =

```
<?php
exec("ffmpeg -ss 00:00:01 -i demo.mp4 -f image2 -y test1.jpg", $output, $return);
var_dump($output);  //array empty
var_dump($return);   // int 1
?>
```

i dont know how to solve it

Comment: Try to include a full path to your ffmpeg lib i.e /usr/lib/ffmpeg

Comment: Its ffmpeg permission problem.check ffmpeg owner and its permission.

Comment: @rajeshujade i don't know how to check ffmpeg's permission...

Comment: use this command to give execute permission `chmod +x $(which ffmpeg)`. Get full path using ls -lh $(which ffmpeg) and use it in php script